# Wrong Counts and Totals with SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery

I am trying to create a SQL query that displays the payment month, full name of customer, count of payments per month, and the total dollar amount of payments for each month. I want to show the top 10 highest-paying customers. Since showing the top 10 customers requires a total of all payments each customer made for all months, I used a subquery.

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', p.payment_date) as pay_mon, fullname, count(p.payment_date) as pay_countpermon, pay_amount
FROM payment p
JOIN customer c ON p.customer_id=c.customer_id,
  (SELECT c.first_name||' '||c.last_name as fullname, sum(p.amount) as pay_amount
  FROM payment p
  JOIN customer c ON p.customer_id=c.customer_id
  GROUP by fullname
  ORDER BY 2 desc
  LIMIT 10) t1
GROUP BY 2, 1, pay_amount
ORDER BY fullname, pay_amount desc;
```

However, the counts and totals are incorrect and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

[image]
[image]

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why the `limit` ? (in the subquery)

Comment: Do not mix implicit joins (tables separated by commas) and explicit joins (using `JOIN`) in the same statement.

Comment: I used LIMIT 10 in the subquery to limit it to the 10 highest-paying customers. If I use that in the outer query, it will not limit by top payers, even if I change the ORDER BY.

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the base query that calculates the total for all customers:

```
SELECT (c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) as fullname, 
       date_trunc('month', p.payment_date) as pay_mon,
       count(*) as month_count
       SUM(p.amount) as month_amount,
       SUM(SUM(p.amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer_id) as total_amount
FROM payment p JOIN
     customer c
     ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP by c.customer_id, fullname, pay_mon;
```

(Note that this includes `customer_id` in the `GROUP BY`.  This is a good practice in case two customers have the same name.)

Next, you can get the top ten using `dense_rank()`:

```
WITH cm as (
      SELECT (c.first_name || ' ' || c.last_name) as fullname, 
             date_trunc('month', p.payment_date) as pay_mon,
             count(*) as month_count
             SUM(p.amount) as month_amount,
             SUM(SUM(p.amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer_id) as total_amount
      FROM payment p JOIN
           customer c
           ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
      GROUP by c.customer_id, fullname, pay_mon
     )
SELECT cm.*
FROM (SELECT cm.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_amount DESC) as seqnum
      FROM cm
     ) cm
WHERE seqnum <= 10;
```

Note that this will return more than 10 customers if there are ties.  If you want 10 customers exactly, regardless of ties, then use:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_amount DESC, customer_id) as seqnum
```